# rbenv not able to install ruby 2.2.5 and 2.3.1

Tags: ruby, homebrew, rbenv, ruby-2.2, ruby-2.3

I run `brew update` and `brew upgrade rbenv ruby-build`. FYI: I updated xcode to version 8.1 yesterday.

I checked available versions, `rbenv install -l`.

Then I tried to install ruby2.2.5 by `rbenv install 2.2.5`, then I get the following errors.

I tried 2.3.1 but I got the same errors. How can I fix the problem?

```
Downloading ruby-2.2.5.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.2/ruby-2.2.5.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.2.5...

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.11.6 using ruby-build 20160602)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/2p/49l6q0gs6qzgtxbg4h1st_5h0000gq/T/ruby-build.20161106122840.51330
Results logged to /var/folders/2p/49l6q0gs6qzgtxbg4h1st_5h0000gq/T/ruby-build.20161106122840.51330.log

Last 10 log lines:
  Referenced from: /private/var/folders/2p/49l6q0gs6qzgtxbg4h1st_5h0000gq/T/ruby-build.20161106122840.51330/ruby-2.2.5/./miniruby (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: /private/var/folders/2p/49l6q0gs6qzgtxbg4h1st_5h0000gq/T/ruby-build.20161106122840.51330/ruby-2.2.5/./miniruby (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

make: *** [encdb.h] Trace/BPT trap: 5
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [.rbconfig.time] Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Comment: Using the same command as you, I have no errors. I'm using `Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)`. What is the output of `cc -v`?

Comment: @Ortomania: My output: Lokni Apple LLVM version 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Comment: Did you manually install some system libraries?

Answer (score 2):

First, I've uninstalled all:

```
brew uninstall rbenv ruby-build
```

and because of an old sticky ruby-build installation, I've forced like this:

```
brew uninstall --force ruby-build
```

I can see an old invocation for rbenv when I type `ruby -v`. So I remove all rbenv references from `$HOME/.bash_profile` and then reload it with:

```
source $HOME/.bash_profile
```

Now I only see my old default MacOs ruby version:

```
ruby -v     # ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883)
which ruby  # /usr/bin/ruby
```

¡Good! Now it's time to install them again and then list available Ruby versions:

```
brew install rbenv

rbenv install -l
```

I now can see more Ruby options to install...

> 2.2.4, 2.2.5, 2.2.6, 2.2.7, 2.2.8, 2.2.9, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.3.5, 2.3.6, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.5.0

I will choose one of them and make it global:

```
rbenv install 2.5.0
rbenv global 2.5.0
```

I case you don't have already the `$HOME/.bash_profile` rbenv config line, run:

```
rbenv init
```

... and add the resulting line to your `$HOME/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to upgrade rbenv.

```
brew upgrade rbenv
```

Then I got a warning.

```
Warning: You have Xcode 8 installed without the CLT;
this causes certain builds to fail on OS X El Capitan (10.11).
Please install the CLT via:
  sudo xcode-select --install
Error: rbenv 1.0.0 already installed
```

So I installed `xcode-select`.

```
sudo xcode-select --install
```

Then I tried to upgrade rbenv but rbenv 1.0.0 was already installed.

```
brew upgrade rbenv
Error: rbenv 1.0.0 already installed
```

So I tried to install 2.3.1 and 2.2.5

```
rbenv install 2.3.1
...
rbenv install 2.2.5
```

And it was a success.

```
➜  ~ rbenv versions
  system
  1.9.3-p327
* 2.2.2 (set by /Users/sokada/.rbenv/version)
  2.2.5
  2.3.1
```

I also need to install bundle since I came to this problem from using bundle.

```
gem install bundler -v 1.13.6 // newest as of this writing
bundler -v
bundler install // finally I could use it.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a really old question. However, the correct approach I believe is to upgrade `ruby-build`. It is available as a plugin for rbenv that provides the rbenv install command.
so to fix the issue follow this approach: https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build#upgrading

```
# Via Homebrew
$ brew update && brew upgrade ruby-build
```